# wildfly 10.1 and logback: contextName return default

Tags: logging, wildfly, logback, wildfly-10

I'm using Logback in web application deployed on wildfly 10.1
I'm trying to print the web application name on each line

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %contextName [%thread] %level [%logger] - %msg %n</pattern>
```

but it return *default*

i added the context root to the jboss-web.xml

```
<context-root>/mycontext</context-root>
```

i tyed allso with $CONTEXT_ROOT that return also *default*

Comment: Do you have the context name defined in your logback.xml? https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#contextName